# Keras Callback - where to find the monitor string values?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In which documentation of TF/Keras list all the available string values for the monitor argument and their explanations? I saw "val_acc", "val_loss" but what are others?

For instance [EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping):

```
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',              <------------ 
    min_delta=0, patience=0, verbose=0,
    mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False
)
```

Comment: Try `fit` for one epoch. Anything it prints is usable.

Comment: The `metrics` when youu compile the model

Comment: And multiple loss for multiple output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we need to use the `name` attribute of the [Keras metric](https://keras.io/api/metrics/) instance which has been specified at `model.compile`. If the default instance is specified via the default name e.g. "val" or "accuracy", then it is the name attributes.

## Experiment

Specify **"hogehoge"** as the metric name of `tf.keras.metrics.AUC`.

```
METRIC_NAME = "hogehoge"

metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name=METRIC_NAME), "accuracy"]
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
    loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=metrics
)
```

Then **hogehoge** and **val_hogehoge** appear as the metric names as the message from `model.fit()`. ```val_`` ` is the prefix for validation metrics as the Keras convention.

```
model.fit(
    x=X,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=V,
    callbacks=[
        ROCCallback(),
    ]
)
----------
...
Epoch 1/5
42/42 [==============================] - 30s 546ms/step - loss: 0.0018 - hogehoge: 1.0000 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0021 - val_hogehoge: 1.0000 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00001: val_hogehoge improved from -inf to 1.00000, saving model to /content/drive/MyDrive/home/repository/mon/huggingface/finetuning/output/run_HOGE/model/model.h5

loss:0.0018227609107270837
hogehoge:1.0
accuracy:1.0
val_loss:0.002101171063259244
val_hogehoge:1.0
val_accuracy:1.0
```

The `logs` argument of the callback method has them as the ROCCallback prints.

```
class ROCCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """calculate ROC&AUC
    """
    def __init__(self):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        [print(f"{k}:{v}") for k, v in logs.items()]
```

#### monitor attribute

To monitor the metrics of the `tf.keras.metrics.AUC` instance, set `hogehoge` for training or  `val_hogehoge` for validation as the `monitor` attribute of the callbacks.

```
MONITOR_METRIC = f"val_{METRIC_NAME}"
MONITOR_MODE = 'max'

class ModelCheckpointCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint):
    def __init__(self, path_to_file, monitor, mode):
        super().__init__(
            filepath=path_to_file, 
            monitor=monitor, 
            mode=mode, 
            save_best_only=True,
            save_weights_only=True,
            save_freq="epoch",
            verbose=1
        )

model.fit(
    x=X,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=V,
    callbacks=[
        ModelCheckpointCallback(MODEL_FILE, monitor=MONITOR_METRIC, mode=MONITOR_MODE),
    ]
)
----------
Epoch 1/5
42/42 [==============================] - 30s 545ms/step - loss: 0.0368 - hogehoge: 0.9993 - accuracy: 0.9821 - val_loss: 0.0038 - val_hogehoge: 1.0000 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00001: val_hogehoge improved from -inf to 1.00000, saving model to /content/drive/MyDrive/model.h5
```

---

## Conclusion

To verify the metrics names to monitor, dump the name of the `metrics` or `metric_names` attribute of the Keras model. Prefix with `val_` to monitor validation metrics.

```
for metric in model.metrics:
    print(metric.name)
----------
loss
hogehoge
accuracy
```

```
print(model.metrics_names)
----------
['loss', 'hogehoge', 'accuracy']
```